# Unable to insert item into SPList using JSOM in IE 11 browser

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jsom, internet-explorer

My code executes if the console window is opened for atleast one time in IE 11  otherwise not running.

I found various articles and posts stating removing "**console**" object and/or  disabling cache during ajax calls will prevent this issue.
 But in my code there is no ajax calls nor console objects. Still the problem persists.

Below is the as usual code for inserting item which works if console is opened.

```
            ...
            ...
            var list= webSite.get_lists().getByTitle('listname')
            var listItemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation()
            var listItem = list.addItem(listItemInfo)
            ...
            ...
            listItem.update()
            clientContext.load(listItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {},function () {});
```

Couldn't understand the actual reason for this behaviour.
Have anyone faced this behaviour before.

Is there any way to stop this issue.

**Side Note :**
   If I modify the source code like adding alert(), my code runs for the first time, but next time onwards the same issue. So I guess there must be some type of caching issue.

Comment: did you check if any error are coming in function complete ? try to capture xdata and status in complete function....

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia. No errors are coming.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make sure that `sp.js` file is loaded and after that add the list item

Try code as below:

```
function createListItem() {

    var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("listname");

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');        

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    //console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    //console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem);
```

Comment: Those ``Function.createDelegate`` statements are old specific IE8 code, it will work for now because SharePoint polyfills them, your code might not work in the future

Comment: Thankyou for the answers. Including `sp.js` made my code run but new issue occured. Actually I was trying to override the default behaviour of the publish button in NewPost.aspx page. All I wanted to do is save the post in list myself for some reason. On overriding it worked perfectly in all browsers except IE. In IE two posts are created since, both my function and default behaviour is executed. So I made my logic available inside the `PreSaveAction` method and returned `false`. Now its working correctly.